# How to make call from iphone app on xml parser value?

Tags: iphone, phone-call

I am still not able to make phone call using previous answer. I am parsing xml file to get phone number values (aMarker.phone= phone number). Where marker is attributes in xml file which I am fetching in my parser controller. I am able to set this phone number string on Button title. But by tapping button I am not able to call the number. See my code

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {
 if(BGView.hidden == YES)
{
BGView.hidden = NO;

NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
  marker *aMarker = (marker *)[appDelegate.markers objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
for (int selectedIndexPath = 0; selectedIndexPath < [appDelegate.markers count];    selectedIndexPath++)
{       [p_Bcard setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aMarker.phone]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 //getting correct number on p_Bcard button title.
}
}}
```

Button Action code:

```
 -(IBAction)phonecallUpadated
  {
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

marker *aMarker = (marker *)[appDelegate.markers  objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
for (int selectedIndexPath = 0; selectedIndexPath < [appDelegate.markers count];  selectedIndexPath++)
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aMarker.phone]]];

 //not able to call pressing p_Bcard button using above action. method get call by setting breakpoint.
```

What should I do here to pass proper string number to make phone call.
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all convert your phone number to UTF8 encoding string then make NSURL. another wise set %20 between two words (between two phone no).

Comment: Welcome ....keep in mind that all url related activity worked on iPhone is just worked as safari.

Comment: Can you answer this also plz. I also want to call web link n m using follwing code==                                                 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aMarker.web]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

Comment: Ok use this, but always convert nsstring into utf8 string,because if your string contains space or any other symbols or punctuation mark then it  must be converted according to ios.

Comment: symbols is like only the dots,www.google.com. "." is the only symoble

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165796/how-to-make-call-from-iphone-app-on-xml-parser-value/8166595#8166595"]]; This is tested. It contains .(dot). I think u need to check your url.

Comment: I am calling dynamic url like above phone number.I did this way as u suggested. not working  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aMarker.web]]];

Comment: NSString *utfString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aMarker.web]  UTF8String]; and then use this utfString with NSURL.

Comment: showing EXbad access==NSString *utfString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aMarker.web] UTF8String];  
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:utfString];
  
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

Comment: check aMarker.web. U have problem in that...rest of think is good.

Comment: yes I am getting respective weblink in console by NSloging. Like when I removing UTF8String it shows www.google.com as aMarker.web

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5116/discussion-between-sudesh-kumar-and-navnath-memane)

Answer (score 0):

To make phone call, you need to have append `tel:` with the phone number.
It should be as follows:

```
NSString *phone_number = @"18005551212"; // get dynamically from your code
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phone_number]]];
```

Comment: No success .....NSString *phone_number = aMarker.phone; [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phone_number]]]; NSLog(@"%d",phone_number);// setting NSlog it gives 1784768 where my button title cell no. is 022 2294 8602.

Comment: I think I am not able to get the right string to make phone call. But then How the button title is showing right number???

Comment: `NSLog(@"%d",phone_number);` You are using %d to print the string value. Use %@ to print the correct value.

Comment: yes It is printing right number by NSLog(@"%@",phone_number); then not able to call. How???

Comment: Can you answer this also plz. I also want to call web link n m using follwing code==                                                 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aMarker.web]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];