# How to call weblink in safari from iphone application query

Tags: iphone, email, mobile-safari

I am parsing xml file to get phone number values (aMarker.web= weblink). Where marker is attributes in xml file which I am fetching in my parser controller. I am able to set this webLink string on Button title by using

```
        [w_Bcard setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aMarker.web] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But by tapping button I am not able to call the number. See my code

```
 - (IBAction)weblink_BcardVeiw
   {

NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

marker *aMarker = (marker *)[appDelegate.markers  objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row];
 for (int selectedIndexPath = 0; selectedIndexPath < [appDelegate.markers count];  selectedIndexPath++)
 {
    NSString *utfString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aMarker.web];        
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:utfString];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
   }
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:YES];
```

By NSloging m getting respective url but not able to open this url in safari. Where should I correct the above code???
I also want to call mail application by passing dynamic string aMarker.email. Can you suggest that code also.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a data detector. For instance, you might do something like this:

```
- (void)dataDetectorPassInRange:(NSRange)range
{
    if (![self dataDetectorTypes])
            return;

    NSError* error = NULL;
    NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:self.dataDetectorTypes error:&error];
    NSAssert(error == nil, @"Problem creating the link detector: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSString* string = [self yourStringStore];

    [detector enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult* match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL* stop){
            NSRange matchRange = [match range];
            if([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber)
            {
                    NSString* phoneNumber = [match phoneNumber];
                    NSURL* phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber];
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneURL];
            }
    }];
}
```

I do something like this in some code where I create a replacement UITextView which can handle attributed text (styled) and detect things like phone numbers, links and addresses. Basically what you want are data detectors.

Comment: I have just able to do a phone call from application. I didn't use dattdetector thing...  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165796/how-to-make-call-from-iphone-app-on-xml-parser-value/8166595#8166595